# Using arrayformula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to use arrayformula to expand the formula below but it's not working. When I copy-paste manually the formula into each cell it works.

```
=arrayformula(INDEX($1:$100,ROW(B2:B),match(YEAR(M$1:$1),$1:$1,0)))
```

What I want to achieve is to convert yearly salaries into monthly salaries based on years.

The spreadsheet can be viewed here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1veiYh1CMIfFPwBGQk4OwKmCLa7q08TugReVfAXtpIgI/edit#gid=1363287956

Thanks!

Comment: The sheet doesn't allow access.

Comment: Sorry it's fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Since you are looking for a specific column, you can use [HLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375?hl=en) as a substitute for INDEX and MATCH:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(YEAR(M1:AT1),A1:H11,ROW(B2:B11))/12)
```

This should yield the same result as the previous formula:

[image]